# How to trigger UILocalNotification if fireDate day > last day of month?

Tags: swift3, uilocalnotification, repeat

Experts, any help would be appreciated.

I have a UILocalNotification set for January 30 at 2:00pm and it repeats monthly (`localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.month`).  It triggers on March 30 at 2:00pm (all of this is working great).

But in February, the local notification won't trigger since there is no 30th day of the month.

Is there any way for me to have the notification trigger on the last day of the month if the fireDate is greater than the last day of the month?

**EDIT**
Below is a partial solution building on the suggestions of @MirekE:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

    print("comparing fireDate to nextMonthLastDayDate..")
    //get the fire date of the notification received
    let notificationFireDate = notification.fireDate

    //get the last day of the next month
    let now = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    guard let days = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: now) else { preconditionFailure("Range of days can't be calculated") }
    let lastDay = days.upperBound - 1
    var lastDayComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: now)
    lastDayComponents.day = lastDay
    guard let lastDayDate = calendar.date(from: lastDayComponents)  else { preconditionFailure("Date can't be calculated from components") }
    let nextMonthLastDayDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: lastDayDate)

    //if the firedate is greater than the last day fo the next month...
    if notificationFireDate! > nextMonthLastDayDate! {
        //then set the firedate to the last day of the next month
        notification.fireDate = nextMonthLastDayDate
        print("did set fireDate = nextMonthLastDayDate : \(notification.fireDate)")
    } else {
        print("fireDate < nextMonthLastDayDate.  fireDate not changed : \(notification.fireDate)")
    }   
}
```

Now, when the notification originally set for January 30 (and monthly repeat) is received, it's new fireDate will be changed to February 28.

But, it will fire on March 28 the next after that (instead of March 30).  Any thoughts on how to make sure this goes back?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you could consider:

Express current date as components, then replace the `.day` with value of last day and convert back to `Date` and/or use `Calendar.date(from: DateComponents...)`

```
let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
guard let days = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: now) else { preconditionFailure("Range of days can't be calculated") }
let lastDay = days.upperBound - 1

var lastDayComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: now)
lastDayComponents.day = lastDay

guard let lastDayDate = calendar.date(from: lastDayComponents)  else { preconditionFailure("Date can't be calculated from components") }

let nextMonthLastDayDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: lastDayDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've made some edits above.   Now when the notification originally set for January 30 (and monthly repeat) is received, it's new fireDate will be changed to February 28.
But, it will fire on March 28 the next after that (instead of March 30). Is there a way to make the fireDate = 30 for March after being set to 28 for February?